# What's wrong with == operator on java string

Tags: java, string

I have,
 `String str1 = "StringA";`
 `String str2 = "StringA";`

Now, I do

`(str1 == str2)`

Sometimes it doesn't match the strings and returns `false`

But `str1.equals(str2)` always returns `true`

What I'm missing here?
I cannot always use `equals` as my `String` can be null also.

Thanks!

Comment: This question was asked O(∞) times.

Comment: This is Java 101 and is covered in the FAQ section of [this site's Java tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info).

Comment: @MarounMaroun That's the *lower bound* on the number of such questions :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`==` compares references not the content

To compare strings you need to use [String#equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29):

```
.equals(); //If you  consider the case
.equalsIgnoreCase(); //If you not consider the case
```

Answer (score 1):

`==` compares the exact values. So it compares if the `primitive` values are the same,

`.equals()` calls the `comparison` method of `objects`, which will compare the actual objects pointed by the references. In the case of Strings, it compares each character to see if they're `equal`.

**Read more here :**

- [Why doesn’t == work on String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17443201/why-doesnt-work-on-string/17443215#17443215)

---