# Why doesn’t == work on String?

Tags: java

I just started Java programming. I love it so far, but I have been stuck on this problem for a while.

When I run this code, whenever I type in “boy” it will just respond with `GIRL`:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ifstatementgirlorboy {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Are you a boy or a girl?");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String gender = input.nextLine();

        if(gender=="boy") { 
            System.out.println("BOY");
        } 
        else { 
            System.out.println("GIRL"); 
        }
    }
}
```

Why?

Comment: use equals instead of == for string in java. Check other questions on this site for more precisions about this.

Comment: This has been asked a lot of time in SO. Please take a while to explore before posting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: whenever someone compares Java `String`s with `==` a Developer cries...

Comment: Oh god... you know you haven’t done Java in a while when you’re suddenly get flashbacks to pointer exam questions the second == is brought up

Comment: "Why doesn't == work on String`? It _does_ work!  It just **doesn't do what you normally want** when you're asking if one string is "equal to" another.

Comment: None of these answers explains the deeper "why can't you compare strings using ==?" As in the foundation of the decision in the language specification. For someone who has no experience of C, it's entirely counterintuitive.

Comment: This is the answer you were looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14123474/912829

Answer (score 30):

Use the `String.equals(String otherString)` function to compare strings, not the `==` operator.

This is because the `==` operator only compares object references, while
the `String.equals()` method compares both `String`'s values i.e. the sequence of characters that make up each `String`.

[equals() method from Source code of String:](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.equals%28java.lang.Object%29)

```
        public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
1013        if (this == anObject) {
1014            return true;
1015        }
1016        if (anObject instanceof String) {
1017            String anotherString = (String)anObject;
1018            int n = count;
1019            if (n == anotherString.count) {
1020                char v1[] = value;
1021                char v2[] = anotherString.value;
1022                int i = offset;
1023                int j = anotherString.offset;
1024                while (n-- != 0) {
1025                    if (v1[i++] != v2[j++])
1026                        return false;
1027                }
1028                return true;
1029            }
1030        }
1031        return false;
1032    }
```

So you should write

```
if(gender.equals("boy")){

}
```

or to comapre with regardless of case

```
if(gender.equalsIgnoreCase("boy")){

}
```

and for null safety

```
if("boy".equals(gender)){

}
```

---

**Future reference:**

```
String s1 = "Hello";              // String literal
String s2 = "Hello";              // String literal
String s3 = s1;                   // same reference
String s4 = new String("Hello");  // String object
String s5 = new String("Hello");  // String object
```

Here   `s1 == s2 == s3 but s4 != s5`

Where as

`anyOfAbove.equals(anyOtherOfAbove); //true`

Comment: Or, even better, `"boy".equals(gender)` because this works even if `gender == null`.

Comment: and `equalsIgnoreCase()` would be even better :D

Comment: @Tichodroma Sometimes if something is `null`, you should take care of it.. So you actually want to see the NPE in order to prevent this.. However, if you **can** set some String to `null` in purpose.. then this attitude is very good.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: If null is expected and to be treated differently then checking for `null` would be better to catch the NPE

Comment: Java is the weirdest language ever

Answer (score 7):

When comparing objects of type `String`, you should use the `equals` method instead of operator `==`.  `equals` will compare the values of `String` objects while `==` checks to see if they are the same object in memory.

So instead of:

```
if(gender=="boy")
```

use

```
if(gender.equals("boy"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `equals` instead of `==`

```
if("boy".equals(gender)){

}
```

use **equals** To compare the value. while `==` is compare object reference.

Answer (score 1):

```
String a,b;

a==b;
```

here references(addresses) of both string objects are compared

```
a.equals(b);
```

here contents of both strings are compared

Answer (score 1):

In Java, strings are objects (`String`). Variables which contain objects are references. If you compare two objects with `==` operator, `true` is returned only if they are the same objects (in memory). But in your code they aren't (`"boys"` is an instantialized String on the fly).

There is, however, a method `String.equals()`, which compares two strings and returns true if they have the same characters in the same order, not if they are the same objects.

Correct code here:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ifstatementgirlorboy {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Are you a boy or a girl?");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String gender = input.nextLine();

        if (gender.equals("boy")) {
            System.out.println("BOY");
        } 

        else {
            System.out.println("GIRL");
        }
    }
}
```

You can also swap the two strings (the advantage is that it prevents `NullPointerException` from being thrown if `gender == null`):

```
"boy".equals(gender)
```

To ignore the case of letters in comparison, use `equalsIgnoreCase()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

you cant compare strings like that in java, You need to use

```
if (gender.equals("boy"))
```

for it to work. Your way is comparing the object rather than the content

Comment: Thanks for these quick answers. First time here on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You're using *reference* equality there. The `==` is literally comparing the 2 references. i.e. are they the same object.

You need to use the `equals()` method, which (in this case) will compare the *contents* of the two strings. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus) for more info.

Comment: correct,  but should his code not work, too? strings are internalized, so when reading "boy" the ref should both point to the same "boy" string object?