# Is Java String immutable?

Tags: java, string, immutability

I don't understand this code, why my string `c` don't changing in `main` method but changing in `changeString`. Can you explain me?

```
class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String c = "lalala";
        changeString(c);
        System.out.println("str in main = "+c);
    }

    public static void changeString(String str) {
        str = str + "CHANGE!!!";
        System.out.println("str in changeString = "+str);
    }

}
```

Result:

```
str in changeString = lalalaCHANGE!!!
str in main = lalala
```

Comment: There are may be a thousand duplicate questions for this in Java. Check those on the related section on the right hand panel of this page

Comment: This link will explain you concept of string in Java [check this][1]


  [1]: http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2010/10/why-string-is-immutable-in-java.html

Comment: I was writing up an answer to this.  You really should read http://python.net/~mwh/hacks/objectthink.html if you want to understand how variables work.  Though the post is in Python, the concept is the same in languages that employ references to values. *TL;DR - variables are names bound to objects not buckets that hold objects*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the java string is immutable.

In `changeString`, you are passing in a reference to the string `lalala` and then you are changing the *reference* to one that points to `lalalaCHANGE!!!`. The original string object is not changed, and the reference in `main` still refers to that original object.

If you were to use a StringBuilder instead of a string, and append `CHANGE!!!` to that StringBuilder, then you would see the change reflected in viewing it at main:

```
class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder c = new StringBuilder("lalala");
        changeString(c);
        System.out.println("str in main = "+c.toString());
    }

    public static void changeString(StringBuilder str) {
        str.append("CHANGE!!!");
        System.out.println("str in changeString = "+str.toString);
    }

}
```

In this changed version you would get:

```
str in changeString = lalalaCHANGE!!!
str in main = lalalaCHANGE!!!
```

Comment: This link will explain you concept of string in Java [check this][1]


  [1]: http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2010/10/why-string-is-immutable-in-java.html

Comment: @yantrakaar Why are you commenting that to me? Comment directly to the OP perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

> Is Java String immutable?

String is immutable and it  means that you cannot change the object itself, but you can change the reference ofcourse.

So when you do this in your `changeString` method:

```
str = str + "CHANGE!!!";
```

a new string memory object is created. But your `c` reference in `main` method is still pointing to the old sting memory object and hence prints `lalala`.

Answer (score 1):

String is immutable, of course:

> Note: The String class is immutable, so that once it is created a
>   String object cannot be changed. The String class has a number of
>   methods, some of which will be discussed below, that appear to modify
>   strings. Since strings are immutable, what these methods really do is
>   create and return a new string that contains the result of the
>   operation.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html

```
str = str + "CHANGE!!!";
```

this code is returning a different String and replacing its reference into you variable, but the original String didn't change.

Answer (score 0):

Yes ,Java [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) is Immutable.

> Strings are constant; their values cannot be changed after they are created.

[And String in java has very special treatment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17489250/how-can-a-string-be-initialized-using)

**Read more here :**

- [Why doesn’t == work on String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17443201/why-doesnt-work-on-string/17443215#17443215)

---