# String sent through a socket doesn't match what it should be

Tags: java, flash, sockets

Using a PrintWriter in java (server) to send data through a socket:

**JAVA**

```
out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
out.println("p1");
```

Then when I get this value in flash (client):

**FLASH AS3**

```
line = socket.readUTFBytes(socket.bytesAvailable);
```

This if statement is not run:

```
if (line == "p1") {
```

And when I trace line to, I get p1 in the output (though when I put in a breakpoint and run in debug, it shows line as being equal to "p1, rather than "p1").

Comment: and what about `if ( line.indexOf("p1") >= 0 ) {`

Comment: Aside from anything else, string comparisons with `==` don't work as you expect them to. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: [Why doesn’t == work on String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17443201/why-doesnt-work-on-string/17443215#17443215)

Comment: Maybe I didn't make it very clear, but the if statement is in flash AS3, and == for strings work fine in it as far as I know.

Comment: @IBOED2 - that's quite a key bit of info

Comment: I did mention that line was in flash, sorry if I didn't make it very clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because

```
out.println("p1");
```

will append a line separator (line feed and/or carriage return, depending on platform, configuration etc.). I suspect that's why your debugger show the value as `"p1` (since the next line would contain the closing quote). I suspect you want:

```
out.print("p1");
```

and close or flush the writer (as appropriate).

I note your comment that your string equality is performed in Flash (so the `.equals()` comments don't apply)

Comment: `out.print("p1");` Doesn't seem to do anything, because flash is waiting for an end of line character I think?

Comment: Note my comment re. closing/flushing

Answer (score 0):

To compare String objects in java use .equals() method instead of "==" operator

```
if (line == "p1")
```

should be

```
if (line.equals("p1"))
```

Answer (score -1):

Check with line.toString()
if (line.toString() == "p1") {

Comment: Why? No reason given. Is this even legal Flash? If it's Java, `line` already is a `String.` Pointless answer.