# If statement getting true value

Tags: java

My program is using the following code

```
String mobile="";
if(mobile!="")
System.out.println("++++++");
System.out.println("------");
```

But if statement always set true. how it is possible? how to correct the code to get false for if condition?

Comment: What output do you get? It looks like you might want some braces there, and possibly an `else` clause.

Comment: [why doesnt ==  work on string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17443201/why-doesnt-work-on-string/17443215#17443215)

Comment: In this case, with the given code, both strings are interned; however, first start with `equals`, and then ask a different question using this revised approach if problems persist.

Comment: You have to see [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java?lq=1)

Comment: In the example you give `mobile != ""` is always false. i.e. you have provided you own example of when it is false.  Most likely you have left out some important details.

Comment: if(mobile != null && (!"".equals(mobile.trim()))){
   //code here..
  } this code working correclty for me. thanks for all.

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
if(!(mobile.equals("")))
```

there are difference between `==` and `.equals()`
 As whoAmI has suggested its better to

```
if(!("".equals(mobile)))
```

because it can handle mobile as null

Comment: I would suggest using "".equals(mobile) as it can handle mobile as null.

Comment: @whoAmI as you suggested,I have modified my answer

Comment: It's only better to use `"".equals(mobile)` if you don't want an NPE on null.  [That's not always the best idea.](http://thecodelesscode.com/case/115)  Tolerating null can mask deeper problems in an application.

Answer (score 0):

you can't use "!=" on strings. This only compares the references of the strings. If you want to compare the content of the strings you need to use `equals`

```
if(!("".equals(mobile)))
```

Comment: There are no pointers in Java.

Comment: You are right my friend.But It is just half truth. Pointer is not available for user. But Java use pointer for memory allocation. You got my point?

Comment: @chintan No. I do not. The JLS does not talk about pointers. And there are are Java VMs written in languages that *do not* have pointers. Thus, Java *does not* have pointers and Java/JVM implementations *need not have* pointers. (`NullPointerException` is just poorly named legacy.)

Comment: @user2864740 I have read some where i don't remember. I can get this code. can you explain me how is it work?
Object p1, p2;

p1 = new Object;

p2 = p1;

p1 = null;