# If block not recognizing string

Tags: java, if-statement

```
for (int i = 0; i< expArray.length; i++){
            System.out.println(expArray[i]);
            if ( expArray[i] == "5" ){  ///WHY IS THIS NOT WORKING!!!??             
                System.out.println("here");
```

I know the output of the `System.out...`:

```
0
=
0
+
5
```

This is how my `String` array was made:

```
    for (int i = 0; i< expArray.length; i++){
        if(varTable.get(expArray[i]) != null){
            expArray[i] =  Integer.toString((int) varTable.get(expArray[i]));
        }
    }
```

So the issue is, at the `expArray[i] == "5" )` if block up top its not going in at `i=1` where it should. any reason/thoughts?

Comment: Description might help :[Why doesn’t == work on String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17443201/why-doesnt-work-on-string/17443215#17443215)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use nullsafe check, if you have a constant

```
if("5".equals(expArray[i]))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Use .equals() instead of == for String comparison!
```

== compares if both references point to the same object or not which is not your case. .equals() checks the actual String content.

For detailed explanation on String comparison check out this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

Answer (score 3):

Should use `equals` instead of `==`

```
if(expArray[i].equals("5"))
```

Answer (score 2):

`==` is bad for comparing Strings (any objects really, unless you know they're canonical). `==` just compares object references. .equals() tests equality. For Strings, often they'll be the same but as you've discovered that's not guaranteed.

In Java, one of the most common mistakes newcomers meet is using `==` to compare Strings. You have to remember, `==` compares the object references, not the content.

So, use `if(expArray[i].equals("5")`)

Answer (score 1):

[DO NOT COMPARE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) `String` using `==`