# i want to compare String array with String array but i not successful

Tags: java, arrays, string

```
String [] abcd={"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","N","M","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"};
JButton [] efgh = new JButton[abcd.length];
String [] secretWord={"S","W","I","N","G"};
JTextField [] input= new JTextField[secretWord.length];
String assign;
String [] content = new String[5];

for(int a=0;a<abcd.length;a++)
    {
        if(e.getSource()==efgh[a])
        {
            efgh[a].setEnabled(false);
            if(i<input.length)
            {
                input[i].setText(abcd[a]);
                i++;
            if(i==input.length)
            {   
                for(c=0;c<input.length;c++)
                    {
                        assign=input[c].getText();
                        content[c]=assign;
                        System.out.print(content[c]);

                    }
            }
        }
    }
        if(c==4)
        {
            if(content[0] == secretWord[0]) && content[1]==secretWord[1] && content[2]==secretWord[2] && content[3]==secretWord[3] && content[4]==secretWord[4])
            {
                output1.setText("You are right!!!!");
            }
            else
            {
                output1.setText("Try again!!");
            }
        }

    }
```

when user click the button at all , i want to proceed the step content[value] with secretWord[value], but always got "Try Again".. where are the statement i have been wrong??please me thank you very much..

Comment: compare strings with `.equals()` not `==`

Comment: [Why doesn’t == work on String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17443201/why-doesnt-work-on-string/17443215#17443215)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

Compare strings with `.equals()` not `==`

```
if(content[0].equals(secretWord[0])) && .... 

-or-

if(content[0].equalsIgnoreCase(secretWord[0])) && ....
```

Comment: i use your method and i solved it.. thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the the prior answer recommending using .equals in this situation. However, there is another technique for simplifying this code. If you want to do with arrays something that is easy with List objects, and supported for all List implementations, you can use `Arrays.asList` to get a List view of your arrays:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String [] secretWord={"S","W","I","N","G"};
    String [] content = new String[5];
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(secretWord).equals(Arrays.asList(content)));
    content[0] = "S";
    content[1] = "W";
    content[2] = "I";
    content[3] = "N";
    content[4] = "G";
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(secretWord).equals(Arrays.asList(content)));    
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for better approach

Comment: Maybe better to use Arrays.equals(secretWord, content)?

Comment: thank you for reply..content[] have to null and store the value input from user, so i can't initialize..

Comment: The code creating the arrays in my example code is just to set up a test case. The principle is in getting the comparison done for you, either the way I suggested or by @mmdw's even better approach.