# No exception still not coming out of while loop

Tags: java, android, while-loop

Following is my java code block
i am not able to come out of while block, the same code run's perfect in other module. kindly help me

```
public void current_ER(View v){
        try{ 
                String[] parameters= {uid};
                Caller c=new Caller();

                c.url="current_ER.php";
                c.parameters=parameters;
                c.join(); c.start();

                String result=MainActivity.result;
                System.out.print("before while");
                while(result=="START") {
                    try {
                          Thread.sleep(10); 
                          System.out.print(result); 
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex) { 
                          ex.getLocalizedMessage();
                    System.out.print("in catch"); 
                    }
                }
                System.out.print("after while");    
                Toast.makeText(this, "ER Details->"+result , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                {                   
                    System.out.print("before start indent block");
                    /////////to next screen////
                    Intent Manage_Expense=new Intent(this,Manage_Expense.class);
                    Manage_Expense.putExtra("er_details", result);
                    //MainActivity.result="START";
                    Toast.makeText(this, "ER Details->"+result , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //startActivity(Manage_Expense);
                }

}catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());

}

    };
```

Comment: [When a developer compare strings with `==`, He cries :)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17443201/why-doesnt-work-on-string/17443215#17443215)

Comment: You never change the value of result in your loop either, does another thread change it?

Comment: i have replaced my code   while("START".equals(result))   but still i am not able to get next line out of while loop

Comment: @TimB yes another thread change it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, use:

```
while("START".equals(result))
```

In order to compare Strings.

The main error is that you never update `result`.

At first you set:

```
String result=MainActivity.result;
```

So `result` and `MainActivity.result` points to the same object.
However, in the other thread you update:

```
MainActivity.result=resp;
```

Causing `MainActivity.result` to point to `resp`, but `result` **still points to previous value**.

If you want to check a variable in a loop, you must make sure the value is changed inside the loop.

Comment: You're too fast for me is who you are! +1

Comment: no thats too not working

Comment: Where do you update `result` value?

Comment: calling it from thread

Comment: Can you add the code too?

Comment: public void run(){
        try{
            rs=new Response_From_Server();
            String resp=rs.response_Data(url, parameters);
           MainActivity.result=resp;
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {ex.getLocalizedMessage();}    
    }

Comment: Not here. to the question

Comment: i tried to add in question it is not accepting more code............and in while loop when i am printing result it shows updated vaule

Comment: And the updated value is "START"?

Comment: no my default value is "START" and updated is my 'ER NO'

Answer (score 1):

When you're going to compare 2 strings it's better to use `String.equals()`, `==` operator better works on primitives but not on objects.

Answer (score 0):

As well as using `String#equals()` make sure the variable is marked as `volatile` so threads can see changes made by other threads.

Answer (score 0):

```
i updated my code as follows and it worked 

 System.out.print("before while");
               while("START".equals(MainActivity.result)) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10); 
                        System.out.print(MainActivity.result); 
                    }catch(Exception ex) { ex.getLocalizedMessage();
                    System.out.print("in catch"); 

                    }
                }
```

but i am still unable to figure out why my original code didn't work

Comment: thanks all for your instant and valuable guidance