# Check Radio Button & Select Dropdown List According To Value Retrieved From Database in JSP

Tags: java, database, jsp, radio-button, html-select

My goal is to retrieve value from database and show in JSP.

**Radio button**

If the database data is Owner, the Owner radio button will be check. If the database data is Cashier, the Cashier will then be check.

**Dropdown list**

If the database data is Orange, then the Orange option will be selected.

Below are my codes.

Help will be appreciate. Thanks! :)

**Radio button**

```
<input type="radio" name="role" id="Owner" value="Owner" <c:if out='${staff.staffRole} == "Owner"'>checked</c:if>/>

<input type="radio" name="role" id="Cashier" value="Cashier" <c:if out='${staff.staffRole} == "Cashier"'>checked</c:if>/>
```

**Dropdown list**

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option>Orange</option>
    <option>Durian</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `${staff.staffRole} == "Owner"`  [Please compare strings with equals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17443201/why-doesnt-work-on-string/17443215#17443215)

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ I already changed into <c:if out="(${staff.staffRole}.equals("Owner"))">checked</c:if> .. But still cannot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Radio Buttons:

```
    <c:choose>
  <c:when test='${staff.staffRole == "Owner"}'>
    <input type="radio" name="role" id="Owner" value="Owner" checked >
  </c:when>
<c:otherwise>
  <input type="radio" name="role" id="Owner" value="Owner">
</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
<c:choose>
  <c:when test='${staff.Cashier} == "Owner"}'>
    <input type="radio" name="role" id="Cashier" value="Cashier" checked >
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
    <input type="radio" name="role" id="Cashier" value="Cashier" value="Owner">
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

For DropDown
assuming your data is in bean same bean under staffFruit

```
            <select class="form-control">
            <c:choose>
                  <c:when test='${staff.staffFruit == "Apple"}'>
                    <option selected>Apple</option>
                  </c:when>
                <c:otherwise>
                  <option>Apple</option>
                </c:otherwise>
            </c:choose>
            <c:choose>
                  <c:when test='${staff.staffFruit == "Orange"}'>
                    <option selected>Orange</option>
                  </c:when>
                <c:otherwise>
                  <option>Orange</option>
                </c:otherwise>
            </c:choose>
            <c:choose>
                  <c:when test='${staff.staffFruit == "Durian"}'>
                    <option selected>Durian</option>
                  </c:when>
                <c:otherwise>
                  <option>Durian</option>
                </c:otherwise>
            </c:choose>
            </select>
```

This is a simple if else ladder. I would recommend you to use something more convenient one like

Answer (score 0):

You can do it better using simple scriplet of jsp.

**Radio-buttons:**

```
<%
String ownerChecked = "";
String cashierChecked = "";
if(staff.staffRole.equals("Owner")){
    ownerChecked = "checked";
}else{
    cashierChecked = "checked";
}
%>

<input type="radio" name="role" id="Owner" value="Owner" <%=ownerChecked %> />
<input type="radio" name="role" id="Cashier" value="Cashier" <%=cashierChecked %> />
```

**For Dropdown:**

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option selected="<%=staff.staffFruit.equals("Apple") %>">Apple</option>
    <option selected="<%=staff.staffFruit.equals("Orange") %>">Orange</option>
    <option selected="<%=staff.staffFruit.equals("Durian") %>">Durian</option>
</select>
```

Try this and inform me if further assitance is required.

Comment: That's definitely not better. Scriptlets are bad form. Use JSTL.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
${staff.staffRole} == "Owner"
```

To

```
${staff.staffRole == "Owner"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSTL `eq` operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaik.html)

```
<c:if out="${staff.staffRole eq 'Owner'}"> ......
```

Or

```
<c:if out="${staff.staffRole == 'Owner'}"> .....
```