# getIntent() doesnt work for if statements in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm trying to display an image of an activity but I have a couple to choose from. So I used an if statement to be able to tell which to display based on a string, my problem is the string was retrieved from the first activity.

this is the code for sending the Strings to the other activity(part of the code);

```
        details.putExtra("des", des);
        details.putExtra("name", name);
        startActivity(details);
```

and these are the codes for retrieving and setting the images in Image View(part of the code);

```
    username.setText(intent.getStringExtra("name"));
    description.setText(intent.getStringExtra("des"));

    if (intent.getStringExtra("name").equals("Sheilla")) {
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.sis);
    }
```

The image doesn't get displayed if I do this but does get displayed if I try something like

```
    if(true){
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.sis);
    }
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong and suggest a better way.

Comment: Have you put a log to check the value of `name` in the first bit of code?

Comment: Yes it would appear that the value of "name" is not what you think it is. Put a log statement right before the if statement to check the value of "name"

Comment: The below answer seem good, but ill also suggest try using `equalsIgnoreCase` method to check the name Sheilla...

Comment: Actually, its the same because there is textview on the second activity that makes use of the name and it displays "Sheilla".

Comment: Just for grins try this `String s = intent.getStringExtra("name").trim();` then `boolean b = s.equalsIgnoreCase("Sheilla");` and see what happens when you now try `b` in your `if` statement.

Comment: From where do you try to read the intent from, from onCreate or from onNewIntent?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
        Intent intent = getIntent();
```

Then read values

```
if (intent.getStringExtra("name").equals("Sheilla")) {
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.sis);
}
```

Try reading values

Comment: I've done all declarations already. that particular one is in the codes.

Comment: Try printing values and check if you are getting same.you will get null value if get intent getStringExtra doesn't return any value.

Comment: @Justcurious if it were null then the name wouldn't show in the `TextView`

Comment: equalsIgnoreCase() instead of equal()

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this?

```
    if (intent.getStringExtra("name").trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Sheilla") || intent.getStringExtra("name").trim() == "Sheilla") {
       image.setImageResource(R.drawable.sis); 
     }
```

this code adds some extra validation for the if statements, because sometimes in Java `equals` works and sometimes doesn't. So, you have to put 2 conditions like `equals` and `==`

Comment: Not only is this really poor programing style (2x `intent.getStringExtra("name").trim()` !!) but also it is just wrong. It is widely known that you should never compare Java `String` with `==`.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17443201/why-doesn-t-work-on-string